# Optimal portfolio as combination of target and minimum tracking error portfolios?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, risk-management, optimization

Dear Quant StackExchange

I seek some intuition for how my portfolio behaves given constraints.

In a universe of say 5 assets, I have a "target portfolio" with weights that are found from risk budgeting, $w_T$. But I also have a benchmark ($w_{BM}$) that I care about minimizing my tracking error volatility towards. That benchmark is invested in some assets (say asset 4 and 5) that I cannot invest in, which gives rise to a further constraint $w_i=0$ for $i=4,5$.

So I'm interested in finding a portfolio of weights ($\hat{w}$) that is as close to the target portfolio $w_T$ as possible at the same time subject to the constraint that tracking error volatility towards the benchmark is below some threshold $\tau$. The other constraint is that weights in asset 4 and 5 in $\hat{w}$ is zero.

I have set up the Lagrangian:
$$L = (w-w_T)'\Sigma(w-w_T) + \lambda_1Aw + \lambda_2[(w-w_{BM})'\Sigma(w-w_{BM}) +\tau] $$
where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix and $A$ is a $5\times5$ matrix of zeros except for the 4th and 5th diagonal entries being 1.

My intuition says that the resulting portfolio should lie somewhere between the target portfolio, $w_T$, and the "minimum tracking error portfolio" (that I get to be):
$$w_{mte} = \underset{\text{s.t. }A'w=0}{\text{arg min }(w-w_{BM})'\Sigma(w-w_{BM})}  = w_{BM}-\frac{\lambda_1}{2}\Sigma^{-1}A$$

But when solving it, I'm not able to show that the optimal portfolio is something like a complex convex combination of the two (think: $\hat{w} = \Gamma w_T + (1-\Gamma)w_{mte}$ where $\Gamma = f(\Sigma^{-1}, \lambda_1, \lambda_2)$)? I guess $\Gamma$ should simplify to the identity matrix when the second constraint is not binding, i.e. $\lambda_2=0$ thereby yielding the target portfolio.

Any help is much appreciated! I'm I on the wrong track here, or is somebody able to derive it?